# Why can Object.prototype.toString.call(foo) detect foo's type?

Tags: javascript

I know that we can detect a variable's type in Javascript like this:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call([]); // [object Array]
Object.prototype.toString.call({}); // [object Object]
Object.prototype.toString.call(''); // [object String]
Object.prototype.toString.call(new Date()); // [object Date]
Object.prototype.toString.call(1); // [object Number]
Object.prototype.toString.call(function () {}); // [object Function]
Object.prototype.toString.call(/test/i); // [object RegExp]
Object.prototype.toString.call(true); // [object Boolean]
Object.prototype.toString.call(null); // [object Null]
Object.prototype.toString.call(); // [object Undefined]
```

But why?

How are these values ([object Array], [object String]...) returned, and what does `Object.prototype.toString` do?

Comment: Things like this are [documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) [amply.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Object.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) basically returns the `[[Class]]` (implementation detail) internal property of the objects. Quoting [the section](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.2) from ECMA Script 5.1 specification, where this is defined

> 1. If the `this` value is `undefined`, return `"[object Undefined]"`.
> 2. If the `this` value is `null`, return `"[object Null]"`.
> 3. Let *O* be the result of calling `ToObject` passing the `this` value as the argument.
> 4. Let *class* be the value of the `[[Class]]` internal property of *O*.
> 5. Return the String value that is the result of concatenating the three Strings `"[object "`, `class`, and `"]"`.

Also,

> The value of the `[[Class]]` internal property is defined by this specification for every kind of built-in object. The value of the `[[Class]]` internal property of a host object may be any String value except one of `"Arguments"`, `"Array"`, `"Boolean"`, `"Date"`, `"Error"`, `"Function"`, `"JSON"`, `"Math"`, `"Number"`, `"Object"`, `"RegExp"`, and `"String"`. The value of a `[[Class]]` internal property is used internally to distinguish different kinds of objects. **Note that this specification does not provide any means for a program to access that value except through `Object.prototype.toString`.**

So, `Object.prototype.toString` is the only function which can access the `[[Class]]` property.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using ECMA 6, (Like on NodeJS, or Newer browser tech) you can use the following function to get 'class name'.

```
// primitives
var array = [], obj = {}, str = "", date = new Date(), 
            num = 1, flt = 1.0, reg = new RegExp(/woohoo/g), 
            bool = true, myType = new MyType(), udf = undefined, nul = null;

// names of various types (primitive and not)
var names = cName(array) + ", " + cName(obj) + ", " + cName(str) + ", " +
            cName(num) + ", " + cName(flt) + ", " + cName(reg) + ", " + 
            cName(bool) + ", " +  cName(date) + ", " + cName(myType) + ", " + 
            cName(MyType) + ", " +  cName(udf) + ", " + cName(nul);

// custom type
function MyType(){}

console.log( names ); 
// output: 
// Array, Object, String, Number, Number, RegExp, Boolean, Date, MyType, MyType, undefined, null

// implementation
function cName(obj){
    // default to non-null value.
    var ret = '';

    if(typeof obj === 'undefined')  { ret = 'undefined';  }
    else if(obj === null)           { ret = String(obj); }

    else if(typeof obj.constructor !== 'undefined' && obj.constructor !== null){
        ret = obj.constructor.name

        if(ret == 'Function')       { ret = obj.name; }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Although there really are no 'classes', this helps when being passed something like `Array, vs Object, vs. Null` and you want to know which one it is.

calling `typeof` on any of those will return `'object'`. Then there is the the caveat of having to deal with things like `null` and `undefined`.

Calling `Object.prototype.toString()` is heavier than accessing `constructor.name` as there is no conversion from some type to a string, and I believe the `constructor` and `constructor.name` are both member variables, not a `getter`, which means no additional functions are called in retrieving said name.