# Javascript object attributes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototype

I know that all object properties have a name and have attributes like `value`, `configurable`, `enumerable` and `writable`. But [in this](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-prototype-in-plain-detailed-language/) post I read that objects too have attributes like `prototype`, `class` and `extensible`.

I understand that `prototype` attribute is for pointing for the parent object. But what I don't understand is what's `class` attribute? Is there such attribute? And isn't `extensible` is a method of object as `isExtensible()` ?

Comment: No, none of these are _properties_ (like `isExtensible` is), those can all be thought of as _internal slots_; and the actual _property_ `prototype` is something else entirely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In this post I read that objects too have attributes like `prototype`, `class` and `extensible`.

They're not called "attributes" normally but [*internal slots*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots). Usually they are denoted by double brackets to differentiate them from normal properties, i.e. [[prototype]], [[class]] and [[extensible]].

> What is the [[class]] attribute? Is there such attribute?

Not in ES6 any more. The [[class]] internal slot contained information on which kind of builtin type (e.g. Array, RegExp, builtin wrapper) the object was. It was shown when you used the `Object.prototype.toString` method on the object. (Have a look at [Why can Object.prototype.toString.call(foo) detect foo's type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28881720/1048572) or [Why does `Object.prototype.toString` always return `[object *]`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13151809/1048572) for more details - it was also the best way to detect whether an object is an array before `Array.isArray` was available).

Since ES6, there is no such internal slot any more and `Object.prototype.toString` relies on the [`Symbol.toStringTag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag) mechanism now.

> And isn't extensible a method of object as isExtensible()?

No, the [[extensible]] internal slot is the thing that `isExtensible()` accesses, and that `Object.preventExtensions()` can set.

Comment: Thanks, did not know about `internal slots`.