# What is the Javascript [[Environment]] Property?

Tags: javascript, closures

I am reading [Secrets of the Javascript Ninja](http://file:///C:/Users/Dev/Desktop/Secrets%20of%20the%20JavaScript%20Ninj%20-%20John%20Resig%20&%20Bear%20Bibeault%20&%20J_23.pdf) and am trying to figure out where the closure variables of a function are stored.`[[Environment]]` property available on the function identifier:

> Whenever a function is created, a reference to the lexical environment in which the
>   function was created is stored in an internal (meaning that you cannot access or manipulate it
>   directly) property named *[[Environment]]* (this is the notation that we’ll use to mark these
>   internal properties). In our case, the skulk function will keep a reference to the global
>   environment, and the report function to the skulk environment.

All I see on my function is `[[Scopes]]`, which contains the closure scope:

|
[image]

I have two questions:

1. Is `[[Environment]]` a Node.js thing and the equivalent of `[[Scopes]]` on the front end?
2. Is this the best place to check for any closure data on a function?

Comment: 1) This might be browser specific. IE for example does not even show these scopes. But since this [[Scopes]] object in chrome fits the description for [[enviroment]], I would assume they're the same and [[Scopes]] is the Chrome implementation. 2) No idea, I've never been in a situation where checking the storage location of a closured variable of a function was important instead of checking the value of that closured variable.

Comment: The `[[environment]]` as described in the spec text is a linked list. The `[[scopes]]` in your screenshot looks more like an array.

Comment: As your book says, it's not a property. It's an [internal slot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50449953/1048572) (formerly known as [internal property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11003021/1048572)). You cannot access it, and you cannot "check for closure data" on a function. It's just a courtesy of your debugger to make it available for inspection.

Comment: @Bergi Where do you get the spec list?

Comment: @VSO http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/. I can't recommend it for beginners, though

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, also, sick burn bro.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like [[Scope]] is an old name for [[Environment]]; [here](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-functioninitialize)

```
Set F.[[Environment]] to Scope.
```

While ES5 docs call it [[Scope]]; [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2)

```
Set the [[Scope]] internal property of F to the value of Scope.
```

Answer (score 1):

### 1 : Is [[Environment]] a Node.js thing and the equivalent of [[Scopes]] on the front end?

Um ... **I think the question is wrong**. Because both are created in the phase of creation the execution context.

And I think `[[Environment]]` and `[[Scope]]` are completely different.

`[[Scope]]` **contains a list of variables** that can be accessed within a certain scope, which allows you to search for (scope chain) variables.

`[[Environment]]` knows the **lexical environment**. In addition, this is my idea (don't believe it too much because it might be wrong), because there's an Environment, I think you can use closures. Because it refers to an external lexical environment.

### 2 : Is this the best place to check for any closure data on a function?

Yes. As I said in step 1, I think it's appropriate to check the closure data for a function because it refers to an external lexical environment that is larger than itself.

I hope my opinion helps you a lot. If this is wrong, please leave a comment.

I would recommend these sites. Take a look.
[here1](https://hackernoon.com/javascript-execution-context-and-lexical-environment-explained-528351703922) [here2](https://hackernoon.com/execution-context-in-javascript-319dd72e8e2c)